# Fastest way to convert a "native array" to "array" in Railo?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, railo

I have some data in an integer[] Native Array and I want to perform ArrayAppend / ArrayDeleteValue operations on it. I've noticed that this fails silently in Railo 3.3 because the native array types are fixed length (you can change values but not add/remove).

The question is can I convert a native array to a regular coldfusion/railo array object without doing iteration on it? Is there some kind of built-in function/method for this or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one way. `railo_array = ArrayMerge([], my_native_array)`. Not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is as simple as it gets. (There is no way to make the native java array mutable. You must create a brand new array of the mutable variety. FWIW, the same applies to ACF)